# how to download chrome with apk?

Tags: google-chrome, docker, apk

The following Dockerfile does not build (docker build .), and causes undefined error code 199. my-app folder was created with ng new my-app. This I believe is due to protractor chrome-driver not knowing where chromium is installed. I then tried to set ENV variable, with no change.

How do I download chrome, install and set properties correctly so to build the docker container?

```
FROM node:alpine

ADD my-app ./my-app
RUN apk update && \
apk upgrade && \
apk add --no-cache openjdk8 && \
apk --no-cache add curl && \
apk --no-cache add bash && \
#apk --no-cache add chromium && \
npm install -g protractor && \
webdriver-manager update 
ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser 
RUN cd ./my-app && npm run e2e
```